# Show queryset fields in DJango template, where 'values' are used to make some joins

Tags: django

I have the next queryset:

```
fotosslide=IndexHasFotografia.objects.filter(index_idindex=infoindex,ubicacion_fotografiaindex=0).values('fotografia_idfotografia__pk','fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia','fotografia_idfotografia__nombre_fotografia')
```

And I'm trying to access to the values in the template in this way:

```
<img src="{{ fotosslide.fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia }}">
```

But nothing is showed, I have checked the database and all the data is there, I have checked the webpage code but the string isn't there. I don't know if when `values` are used, the fields must be called in other way in the template?

I have displayed images in other templates, but using Django forms, or JSON, so that is not the problem, because I don't even get the image route. Also I have tried with pure strings, not with images, and nothing is shown too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> filter(): Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters. [Django QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter)

When you use `.filter()` it returns a QuerySet not a single object. If you're actually trying to get a single object use [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead. Then you'll be able to access your information as you're already trying.

```
foto_slide=IndexHasFotografia.objects.get(...)
```

---

However, if you want a QuerySet, then you need to iterate over it to get actual instances.

```
foto_slide_queryset=IndexHasFotografia.objects.filter(...)
```

In your template

```
{% for foto_slide in foto_slide_queryset %}
   <img src="{{ foto_slide.fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But I tried that in other query, where I must retrieve a single object, but with `get`, `values` don't work

Comment: Also, how can I show an specific value? Let's say that I want only the first object of the QuerySet in a part of the template, and the third object of the queryset in other part of the template. I tried to do this, but it don't works: `{{ fotosslide[0].ruta_fotografia }}`

Comment: Generally for a single object, you don't actually need to use `values()`. It becomes more efficient when there are more objects. But if you really want/need to use `values()` for single object then you can slice it after `model.objects.filter(..).values(..)[0] but make sure you actually have values.

Comment: I must use values because I need to retrieve data of other models, some joins must be done. I'm going to try that, thank you.

Comment: As for your second comment. You can extract these object in your view and pass them to your template. If you really need that functionality in your templates then you need to write your [own template filter or tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Just for your information, when you use `foto_slide=IndexHasFotografia.objects.get(...)` you still have access the field values. E.g foto_slide.fotografia_idfotografia would still work.

Comment: I think I'm going to extract the values in the view. And for your last answer, I tried to append `.values()` after `.get()` and I had an error, something that IndexHasFotografia don't have a `values` attribute. Probably if I do something like this `foto_slide.fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia`  ? because I need `ruta_fotografia`, but it is stored in other model that is related to IndexHasFotografia trough a foreign key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122956/discussion-between-tiny-instance-and-elg).